# iOS: MobileSDK3.2: Getting the Credentials after authenticating

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am newbie &  trying to integrate SaleForce into our existing APP, need help in getting the credentials after authenticating.
I am using the latest Mobile SDK 3.2  I followed the Mobile SDK Development Guide.
Requirement is to not to authenticate at launch. So as per the guide I used below method.

```
[[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:^(SFOAuthInfo *authInfo) {
           NSLog(@"SFCRM: Auth finished!");
       }       
       failure:^(SFOAuthInfo *authInfo, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"SFCRM:Auth failed: %@", error);
       }];
```

My authentication is successful, now how do I get the credentials, refresh_token etc?
Do I need to implement SFAuthenticationManager or SFOAuthCoordinator delegate? In the app migration section its mentioned that, we don't need implement these delegate in the new mobileSDK.

Thanks,
SKG.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get it work by implementing `SFAuthenticationManagerDelegate`.

Once authentication was successful, this below delegate function will be called with the credentials.

```
- (void)authManagerDidAuthenticate:(SFAuthenticationManager *)manager credentials:(SFOAuthCredentials *)credentials authInfo:(SFOAuthInfo *)info {
    NSLog (@"didAuthenticate %@", credentials);
}
```

Comment: Hey SKG, can you add a little more info about what you did to implement it? I know it's not that complicated but it'd be useful to have the info here for future readers.